# Как настроить демонстрацию картинок в админке django 1.9?

Tags: python, django

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как отображать загруженные картинки в админке django

вот модель

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=900)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    product_price=models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    product_discaunt=models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    product_category=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    product_discription=models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_discription
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_category
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name
    def image_img(self):
        if self.product_image:
            return u'<a href="{0}" target="_blank"><img src="{0}" width="100"/></a>'.format(self.product_image.url)
        else:
            return '(no picture)'
    image_img.short_description = 'Picture'
    image_img.allow_tags = True
```

вот urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store/', include('store.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
}),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

вот admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product_name','product_image', 'image_img','product_price', 'product_category', )
    readonly_fields = ['image_img',]
    fields=('product_name','product_image', 'image_img','product_price', 'product_category', )
"""
    def image_tag(self, obj):
        return '<img src="%s">' % obj.product_image.url
    image_tag.allow_tags = True
"""
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

вот settings.py

```
_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(_PATH, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
"""
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(_PATH, 'static'),
)
"""
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

вот собственно ошибка

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/img/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg
>   Raised by:    django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve

Comment: Файл точно лежит в медиа? Сервер точно запущен на `:8000`?

Comment: да все точно все проверил

Comment: да все точно все проверил
я заметил что эта ошибка только у одной картинки, я удалил пост содержащий её и теперь ошибка такая 
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/dima/PycharmProjects/cornelProject/projectStore/cornelshop/cornelshop/media/img/pr_uAZ7W3m.jpg